# Usefulness of the grid on tablet surface?

Tags: drawing-tablet

There is an unobtrusive grid of points on the surface of some graphics tablets as in this Wacom Intuos:

[image]

What is the purpose of it? Is it possible to take advantage of it in a some manner?

Comment: I've asked myself the same question. I mostly look at the screen while drawing, but I guess you could use the dots to make sure lines are parallel or orthogonal or use them as guide to draw squares and circles?

Comment: Read https://www.art-is-fun.com/grid-method - it's about using grids in art to transfer or copy images.

Comment: @Billy, thanks for your link, I read it, but I don't understand the connection between the *"hardware"* grid on the tablet's surface and the method used in your link.

Comment: Basically it would allow you to copy an image such as a photograph by either drawing a grid over it, or placing a grid on a transparency over it. Then you could use the grid on the tablet so you can get the positioning of the drawn lines.  It's not a digital function - a very old fashioned drawing aid which existed long before computers. You can also use the same method with paper/canvas etc. It's often used as a way to enlarge images.